# How to bind fontawesome icon name in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the font awesome plugin for Vue.js and I have a tree control where I want to show an icon for each item in the tree.  The icon should be based on the type of the node.  I can't get this binding to work.  Am I just doing this wrong or will it not work like this?  What is the best way to do this?

```
<template>
<div>
...
  <font-awesome-icon :icon="iconName" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TreeItem',
    components: {},
    ...
    computed: {
      iconName(){
        switch(...){
          case 0:
            return 'exclamation';
          default:
            return '';
        }
      },
    },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've forked the starter template with an app that lets you add an icon by typing in the icon name and then clicking the add button, available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-star-ym3fu?file=/src/App.vue). You've provided a limited amount of code that (as far as I can see) has nothing wrong with it, so you can either compare your code with the sandbox or provide more code. Maybe your `iconName` is returning `''` for example.

**Original Answer:** You need to import which icons that you want to use.

There's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/tree/master/examples/vue-cli-webpack) of a good starter template that's on their [GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome).

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faExclamation } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faExclamation)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Comment: Yes, that is done in main.js.  That's not the problem here though.  I can use the icons, I just can't bind the icon name to make them dynamic.

Comment: @Sam Updated my answer